# How to get Susy Sass location working and align an element to a central column

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass, susy

I have a three column grid and using the `+span` function works well to define columns. So if I want an element to span one column I do:

```
+span(1 of 3)
```

and two:

```
+span(2 of 3)
```

etc..

I would now like a an element to span one column but at position 2, i.e in the middle column.

The Susy documentation says to use the `at` keyword to specify location like this:

```
+span(1 at 2 of 3)
```

However, this does not work and my column is at the first position i.e on the left.

resulting css:

```
width: 30.303030303%;
float: left;
margin-left: 1.5151515152%;
margin-right: 1.5151515152%;
```

When I do

```
+span(1 at 3 of 3)
```

resulting css:

```
width: 30.303030303%;
float: right;
margin-left: 1.5151515152%;
margin-right: 1.5151515152%;
```

this works correctly and my column is in the third position.

**How can I make the location work to get my column to be at position two?**

Some images to help explain:

At column one:

[image]

At column 3:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

This last example was achieved with:

```
float: none
margin: 0 auto
```

I consider this a hack and it also means that the height is now wrong as there is no float. I don't think this is how you are supposed to work with Susy.

**Versions:**

Compass 1.0.1
Susy 2.1.3

**I am using .sass files, not .scss**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `at` keyword only works to place an element if you are using `isolation`. That's because placement depends on context — items float in relation to other items — and Susy has no way of knowing what other items are around. Isolation fixes that by positioning every element off the left edge. So one option is to use `+span(1 at 2 of 3 isolate)`.

That's not necessarily the best option, though. For simply moving elements around to different positions, I would use the `push` and `pull` mixins.

```
+span(1 of 3)
+push(1)
```

The `push` mixin adds any number of columns (or an arbitrary span) as margins before the given element — pushing it from where it would have been.